# Way to get beginGestureWithEvent/endGestureWithEvent if window isn't frontmost

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, gesture-recognition, appkit

Is there a way to get

```
- (void)beginGestureWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
```

and

```
- (void)endGestureWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
```

calls to a view even if the containing window is in the background?  It seems these calls are only delivered to windows if they are key.

Comment: So I can look at sendEvent at the app level, looking for NSEventTypeBegin/EndGesture.  That solves my problem for non-key windows but only if the app is frontmost.  Still hoping to solve it for app-not-active case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general no. In Leopard and SnowLeopard, gestures are intended to target only the foreground window. As you discovered, the window server will not even send gesture events to background applications.

You could instal an event tap, but those events don't look exactly their the NS equivalents. All the data is there, though, if you really want to dig into it.

Please file a radar asking for this along with why this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

But here's a workaround:

Add a tracking area to your view bounds with options `NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways`

…and activate your application upon `mouseEntered:`

It's non-standard but it will work.